# Every 3 minutes or so, my external sound card in Windows 7 stops working and I have to manually reset sound output

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers

I am using Windows 7 want to hear all the sounds through my speakers connected with the red and white cables which are connected to my external sound card; a [Roland UA-25EX](http://www.roland.com/products/ua-25ex/). But it stops working every 3 minutes or so and I have to change the playback device to digital or internal speakers then back to the sound card again to make it work and I wanna die. What do I do ?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in Windows when the sound card stops working? What version of the sound driver are you using? Also, maybe [this troubleshooting article](http://www.rolandus.com/support/knowledge_base/201979999) might help?

Comment: No i don't get errors it just stops working and i have to switch between the playback device to make it work again and after a couple of times i have to restart to make it go through half a song again. and there is only one version of driver available for windows 7 on the site.

Comment: Can you confirm that the version available on the website is the same that you have installed on your system? You can [verify this using the Device Manager](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN128900/Windows-Vista/7). And did the troubleshooting article help?

Answer (score 0):

Try different drivers: new, old and very old. Sometimes really ancient drivers work better.